# Find all pairs in an array that sum to a given number

Tags: java, algorithm

> Assume you have an array of random integers and a sum value. Find all
>   pairs of numbers from the array that sum up to the given sum in O(n)
>   time. Find all distinct pairs. (1,2) and (2,1) are not distinct.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class PairsSummingToElement {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PairsSummingToElement e = new PairsSummingToElement();
    int[] input = new int[] { 2, 5, 3, 7, 9, 8 };
    int sum = 11;
    HashSet<Pair> result = e.findAllPairs(input, sum);
    for (Pair p : result) {
      System.out.println("(" + p.getElement1() + "," + p.getElement2() + ")");
    }

  }

  public HashSet<Pair> findAllPairs(int[] inputList, int sum) {
    HashSet<Integer> allElements = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> substracted = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashSet<Pair> result = new HashSet<Pair>();

    for (int i : inputList) {
      allElements.add(i);
      substracted.add(i - sum);
    }

    for (int i : substracted) {
      if (allElements.contains(-1 * i)) {
        addToSet(result, new Pair(-i, i + sum));
      }
    }

    return result;

  }

  public void addToSet(HashSet<Pair> original, Pair toAdd) {
    if (!original.contains(toAdd) && !original.contains(reversePair(toAdd))) {
      original.add(toAdd);
    }
  }

  public Pair reversePair(Pair original) {
    return new Pair(original.getElement2(), original.getElement1());
  }

}

class Pair {
  private int element1;

  private int element2;

  public Pair(int e1, int e2) {
    element1 = e1;
    element2 = e2;
  }

  public int getElement1() {
    return element1;
  }

  public int getElement2() {
    return element2;
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return (element1 + element2) * element2 + element1;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof Pair) {
      Pair otherPair = (Pair) other;
      return ((this.element1 == otherPair.element1) && (this.element2 == otherPair.element2));
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No comments on the time complexity, I do have a bunch of other comments:

## Code to interfaces, not implementations

It's better to use `Set<Integer> allElements = new HashSet<Integer>()` (side note: guess you're not on >= Java 7, since you can use diamond operators otherwise) so that users of `allElements` do not need to know that it actually is a `HashSet`. This is just good practice. The lesson here is that it allows the programmer to replace the implementation with another in the future when required.

## Does not `contain`, then `add` to a `Set`

In the following code block:

```
if (!original.contains(toAdd) && !original.contains(reversePair(toAdd))) {
  original.add(toAdd);
}
```

I think the extra check `!contains()` is not really required because `Set.add()`'s [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) says:

> If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns `false`.

So, even if `original` did contain `toAdd`, calling `add()` will leave the set unchanged anyways. I guess this is useful when you're running on a large set of inputs so that there is some short-circuiting done, hence this is strictly just 'food-for-thought' *and not something to frown upon*.

## `hashCode()`

I'm guess there's an implied range of inputs such as all must be positive right? Because your calculation `(element1 + element2) * element2 + element1` will yield the same hash codes when `element1 + element2` equals to `1`, and having a bunch of negative and positive integers (or just `0, 1`) will 'break' this easily. You may want to update your question with any assumptions on the range of inputs.

## How to reverse a `Pair`

I think that you can move your method `reversePair(Pair)` into the `Pair` class itself as such:

```
public final class Pair { // also declared as final

    private final int element1; // also declared as final
    private final int element2; // also declared as final

    public Pair(int element1, int element2) {
        this.element1 = element1;
        this.element2 = element2;
    }
    ...

    public Pair getReverse() {
        return new Pair(element2, element1);
    }
}
```

Using it then becomes slightly easier:

```
if (!original.contains(toAdd.getReverse())) {
  original.add(toAdd);
}
```

## Override `toString()`

Oh yeah, given how you want to print the contents of `Pair` objects in the end, why not just override `toString()` too? :)

Answer (score 4):

This is on top of what @h.j.k. already said very well.

The `addToSet` and `reversePair` don't really make this code easier to understand.
The logic of the `substracted` set,
and the manipulations with signs are confusing.
A simpler logic is possible:

- Put all the numbers in a set (you already do this)
- For each number `num`:

  - If `sum - num` is in the set, and `sum - num` was not already used, then:
  - Add `num` to the set of used numbers
  - Add the pair `(num, sum - num)`

Implemented this way, it looks simpler to me than the original:

```
public Set<Pair> findAllPairs(int[] inputList, int sum) {
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>(inputList.length);
    for (int num : inputList) {
        numbers.add(num);
    }

    Set<Integer> usedNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<>();
    for (int num : inputList) {
        int pair = sum - num;
        if (numbers.contains(pair) && !usedNumbers.contains(pair)) {
            usedNumbers.add(num);
            pairs.add(new Pair(num, pair));
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

This implementation has another advantage:
you don't need a `Set<Pair>`, it could be a `List<Pair>`,
so you don't need the `.equals` and `.hashCode` methods in `Pair`.

The less code you have, the less complex is your solution.
[Some would say](http://www.cc2e.com) that managing complexity (keeping it down) should be the primary technical imperative of software construction.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't check your algorithm, but I think the code could use some object-orientation!

You shouldn't have a `main` method in the class that holds your algorithm. Use a `Program` class, code your `main` there, and keep your `PairsSummingToElement` clean.

```
class Program{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PairsSummingToElement e = new PairsSummingToElement();
        int[] input = new int[] { 2, 5, 3, 7, 9, 8 };
        int sum = 11;
        e.findAllPairs(input, sum);
    }
}
```

Remove the `main` from your class, it doesn't belong there :)

The indentation is quite small, maybe it is this way because of how you posted your code here but I hope your production code has a better indentation. Finally, consider commenting your code, it will be easier to understand your algorithm for other programmers.

Comment: Funny, on your last sentence before your code snippet I thought: "what a hairsplitting". After the first sentence I thought you are right. :-) The important thing is here, that main() doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1):

I see there are couple of really good suggestions which I like whole heartedly. Have a few more to add:

- Lets make methods like `addToSet`, `reversePair` as `private`. These methods should be leaked to the outside world. At the same time, the less your clients know the better.